# What is the || and * operator mean when referring to matrices?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, game-theory

I have the following matrix equation,

$$
Ap || E ==> p || A^* E
$$

What does || and * mean in this context, where A is a n x n matrix, p is a n x 1 matrix, and E is also an n x 1 matrix.

The context is from a Game Theory question revovling around ESS. It is as described below,

For the following symmetric games [A,A^T], find all symmetric equilibrium pairs which use all the pure strategies i.e. find all SE of the form
<p,p>, pi>0 for all i, Which of these are ESS?

And in order to find ESS, the steps are as follows,

[image]

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I added more context, hope it helps

Comment: Maybe it means 'parallel' ?

Comment: what would parallel mean mathematical with regard to matrices

Comment: $A_1p$ and $E$ are not matrices. They are vectors.